# Comparing two curves with peaks

Tags: multilevel-analysis, method-comparison, curves

I have a question about analysis method and I would be very grateful for the help!
So, I have two groups: Active and Placebo, each group is measured for 20 different concentrations (from 1 to 20) 6 times (response_1 - response_6).

pic.1 Active resoults.
[image: pic.1 Active resoults.]

pic.2 Placebo resoults.
[image]

As you can see there are 3 peaks for every responses of Active group.
Do any statistical methods exist to

1. **find correct concentrations of this peaks.**
2. **prove that the peaks are not random, that it is the peaks but not
   the noise or some kind of outlier.**
3. **compare Active and Placebo groups for whole curves or particular
   concentrations.**

What analysis should I use for solve this problems?

[Here is the file](https://communities.sas.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/234929-71113/RAW_ds.csv.zip) with RAW data in .csv format with ',' as delimiter.

Best regards!